# Laravel Eloquent: multiple relationship with 3 foreign keys using Compoship Topclaudy/Awobaz

Tags: laravel, eloquent, key, composite, composite-key

I am developing a project in Laravel and have to use the package Topclaudy/Awobaz Compoships since laravel does not support composite keys

https://i.ibb.co/x8VgjbR/Untitled-1.png

I have three database tables **(schools, programs, degrees) ** which are in a One-To-Many relationship to a fourth table called **school_programs**

They are joined by three conditions. How do I model this relationship in Eloquent using Compoships?

The table **school_programs** has the 3 foreign key columns set as primary key because I need data for each combination of the three to be unique

Also, how would I be able to retrieve records and eager load with this type of database schema

Any solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: care to edit a question to include the scheme?

Comment: <img src="https://i.ibb.co/x8VgjbR/Untitled-1.png"> here it is. I tried putting it in the post but wasn't allowed because I have a reputation less than 10

Comment: hello there and wellcome. when i post a question to SO, I follow this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It is interesting read, Also, there are https://dba.stackexchange.com. The site have more stict rules of posting than above. It is Okay to post a database related question here, but you should search and read the `how to ask` on dba. It may help you to make your question recieve a quicker answer.

Comment: Well, this question is more about the Laravel Framework approach to use with the database design than a generic thing. dba.stackexchange.com is strictly database but my question is about Laravel and Eloquent .

Comment: ..."and eager load with this type of database schema" - I do not see a schema here. If your question is not about databases as such, and more about apps to use with them, feel free to remove all parts of the question that have a mention of a `SQL` concepts. IMO, they clobber your question and do not contribute to the point. The `how to ask` part still apply. I am humbly pointing you to the ***DO NOT*** post images part. And links to images is even... think you got that.

Comment: Well, you should really look at some questions at `dba` web. Take a note about how people ask, how they format a text. How present a schema`s.